# Discussion about merging [led] tag into [grow-lamp] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tagging

I think the tag [led](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/led) is to specific on its own and could be merged into [grow-lamp](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grow-lamp) which is a general naming that could involve LED, HPS and other grow lamp/grow light related questions.

Currently there are 18 questions tagged with [led](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/led) and 25 questions tagged as [grow-lamp](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grow-lamp).

Please share what are your thoughts on this proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree as LED lights are "new" for use as plant lights and much of the advice does not carry over to the more traditional light sources such as HPS and fluorescent.

My take is the people asking about using LED's as a light source are urban dwellers who would not think to use or look for the grow lamp tag.

If we had a tag hierarchy then LED would be a part of grow lamp but that is not possible with the current tag system.

Comment: I see, my only concern is that when someone comes to the side to look up questions about grow lights, they might not found the questions tagged with led. But I am not insisting on the change. :)

Comment: Good answer & interesting points, also, LEDs have applications in Landscaping & along paths, etc. Thank you

Comment: @BenceKaulics, perhaps `grow-lamp` should be added to the questions that currently have `led`. (Only a few have reached the 5 tag limit.)